# Normalized many-to-many schema for client-side data store

Tags: redux, vuex, database-normalization, normalizr

I am developing the browser front end of a social network application. It has lots of relational data, having **one-to-many** (1:m) and mostly **many-to-many** (m:m) relationships as in below list.

I want to use Flux data flow architecture in the application. I am using Vuex.js with Vue.js.

As expressed in the Redux.js docs it is better to have flat, normalized, store state shape for [various reasons](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) for usage with React, and I think that is the case for usage with Vue.js also.

- posts have categories (m:m)
- posts have tags (m:m)
- post has comments (1:m)
- posts have hashtags in them (m:m) // or users creates hashtags
- posts have mentions in them (m:m) // or users creates mentions of users
- users like posts (m:m)
- users follow users, posts, post categories etc. (m:m)
- users favorite posts (m:m)

etc.

I will need to show post feeds with all of its related data of other entities like users, comments, categories, tags. For this, like having a **1:many** relation, holding **the many side** of this relation's data in the **one** side (can be said to be the *parent*), even it is actually **many-to-many**, seems ok for usual querying of them to compose their parent, that is **posts**. However, I will need to query the store state inversely also, for example, getting the **posts** with a certain **category** or **tag**.

In that case, it is not as easy is as doing so for posts. I need a **relation entity** that holds the **id** pairs for the two connected data entity, just like a *join table* or *association table* in RDBMSs, for ease of accessing and updating, avoiding deep digging into state, and also avoiding unnecessary re-renders (that requirement is React or Vue.js and GUI specific).

How can I achieve this relatively easily and effectively, e.g. as one do for **1:many** relations?

Comment: If trying this is not easy and is ineffective, maybe one can goes with **1:m** way but in the SPA router hooks a **on navigate** like callback to achieve a new network request into the route path of the view that needs inverse query. Results can be merged into the object holding the entitiy that is the second **many** side of this m:m relationship.

Comment: Have you tried using the [example](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/tree/master/examples/relationships) as a starting point? Some code for what you have tried would go a long way in helping answer your question.

Comment: I had just skimmed over the example before I have posted this question above. I think it is not the exact suitable thing for the cases I ask. The entities in the example, and generally in the examples about this subject, are **1-to-many** related. From the output in the example link I can see it holds the related entity references in each entity. That does not mean a **m:m** relation. In such relation, **m:m**, I would expect a **join** key, say **postToCategory**, to hold key-value pairs of `"postId": "categoryId"`. However same could be achieved in the way you show in your example.

Comment: I wonder which one is easier to achieve  and effective to use for **m:m** relationships in client side store state especially in Flux applcaitons, may be Redux or Vuex. Holding relation in both entities, say in `posts.categories` and in `categories.posts` similar to your example, or having a **join (association) entity**, say `postToCategory`, and holding key (for posts) value (for categories) pairs as in a relational database system like I have said in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Pursuant to your last comment. I'll present the data structure I currently use for this circumstance:

**Tag**

```
{
 "type": "tag",
 "id": "tag1",
 "name": "Tag One"
}
```

**Tag To Post**

```
{
  "id": "someId",
  "type": "postTag",
  "tagId": "tag1",
  "postId": "post1"
}
```

**Post**

```
{
 "id": "post1",
 "name": "Post 1"
}
```

I found that each side of M:M storing the relationship ids potentially produces **orphans**. The management of these IDs in dual places leads to replicating steps and an increase in cognitive management as all functions managing the M:M happen in two places rather than one. Additionally, the relationship itself may need to contain data, where would this data go?

**M:M Without Entity**

```
{
 "id": "post1",
 "name": "Post 1"
 "tagIds": [
   {id: "tag1", extraAttribute: false} //this is awkward
 ] 
}
```

**Tag To Post - Additional Attributes**

```
{
  "id": "someId",
  "extraAttribute": false,
  "postId": "post1"
  "type": "postTag",
  "tagId": "tag1",
}
```

There are additional options available to speed up extracting tags with minor elbow grease.

**Post**

```
{
 "id": "post1",
 "name": "Post 1"
 "tagIds" : ["tag1", "tag4"]
}
```

Hypothetically, a post would not have more than 20 tags. Making this a generally negligible storage requirement to reduce lookups. I have found no urgent need for this currently with a database of 10000 relationships.

**Ease of access and updating**

1:M is an object directly pointing at what it wants. M:M are two different entities pointing at their relationships. Model that relationship, and centralise the logic

**Rerenders**

> If your application renders long lists of data (hundreds or thousands
>   of rows), we recommended using a technique known as “windowing”. This
>   technique only renders a small subset of your rows at any given time,
>   and can dramatically reduce the time it takes to re-render the
>   components as well as the number of DOM nodes created.

https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists

I feel solutions may be use case specific and subject to broader opinions. I ran into this issue utilising couch/pouch with Vuex and a very large table of 20,000 entries. Again, in production the issues were not extremely noticeable. Results will always vary.

A couple things I try here:

- Load partial data sets: in-file (non-reactive) vs in memory (loaded in Vuex)
- Sort, paginate, search in-file and load results